# Sun Java Web proxy - SSL transactions/sec?

Tags: networking, monitoring, sun, webproxy

I hope this is "close enough to programming" to pass the bar :)

Is there any way to monitor SSL transactions / sec on Sun Webproxy? Preferably with SNMP, but anything goes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by SSL transactions? The proxy cannot see anything except the connection request, everything else occurs inside the encrypted tunnel.

The connection requests are logged in the "access" log, and appear as "CONNECT fully.qualified.domain.name:port"